# UISearchController comes along with navigation iOS8.3

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, ios8.3

I have VC1 & VC2. VC2 has UISearchController(not UISearchDisplayController) and it's added to table header view. 
Steps:
1. I go to VC2 from VC1 by navigating.
2. VC2 i'm pulling down the table view to search(Search bar displayed)
3. Tap on search bar to search(search bar becomes first responder)
4. Now i click back button from navigation the search bar moved to VC1 from VC2.

If i didn't do 3rd step then search bar stays in VC2 itself. Issues is only if search bar becomes first responder or some text on search bar.

How to avoid search bar moves to VC1?. I want "dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation" property to set false. No need overlay while search. If i set this property to true then i can avoid.

Because when this property is true on tap on back button first it resigns first responder from search bar. Then on 2nd tap control goes to VC1. No issue here.

Thanks

Comment: Fixed by dismissing search controller in viewWillDisappear of VC2.